# Calculate average over many data frames having same format?

Tags: r

I have 15 data frames that are exactly identical, but each have different values stored within each column. Each header row is exactly the same.

Here's an example data frame, call it "A":

```
    Product Q1 Q2
1 Product X 10 15
2 Product Y 20 40
3 Product Z 30 50
```

And here's another, call it "B":

```
    Product Q1 Q2
1 Product X 12  5
2 Product Y 25 44
3 Product Z 32 51
```

I would like to calculate the average value across all 15 data frames. Using my two examples, the output would be a similar data frame but with averages. Something like this:

```
    Product   Q1   Q2
1 Product X 11.0 10.0
2 Product Y 22.5 42.0
3 Product Z 31.0 50.5
```

I've searched around for a solution, but to no avail. It seems like the `mapply` function might be what I need, but I'm not sure how best to put it to use here.

Comment: What you need is a better data structure: one big data frame with an extra column with values 'A', 'B', etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
aggregate(.~Product, rbind(A, B), mean)
#    Product   Q1   Q2
#1 Product X 11.0 10.0
#2 Product Y 22.5 42.0
#3 Product Z 31.0 50.5
```

**DATA**

```
A = structure(list(Product = c("Product X", "Product Y", "Product Z"
), Q1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L), Q2 = c(15L, 40L, 50L)), .Names = c("Product", 
"Q1", "Q2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"
))

B = structure(list(Product = c("Product X", "Product Y", "Product Z"
), Q1 = c(12L, 25L, 32L), Q2 = c(5L, 44L, 51L)), .Names = c("Product", 
"Q1", "Q2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"
))
```

Comment: Super simple... Thanks a lot! If the Product column weren't there would there still be a way to aggregate the data frames?

Answer (score 1):

Since the headers match, let's put all of your data frames into one data frame.

```
df <- rbind(A,B,... O)
```

Then we'll use `dplyr` to summarize:

```
require(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Product) %>%
  summarize(Q1_Avg= mean(Q1), Q2_Avg= mean(Q2))
```